# How to update node value in System.Xml.XmlDocument?

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

In PowerShell v3, I've created an XmlDocument object like this:

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$xmldoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmldoc.Load($xmlfile)
```

After some processing, I want to let the user update the value of a node in `$xmlfile`.

Given the node name and new value to be assigned, how do I update `$xmldoc`?

```
$node = StartBoundry
$newvalue = StringValue
```

I understand I can save like this:

```
$xmldoc.Save($xmlfile)
```

The raw XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Author>MYDOMAIN\user.name</Author>
    <Description>my description</Description>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT2M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2015-09-18T09:29:14</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <RandomDelay>PT3S</RandomDelay>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
...
```

I've experimented with XPath like this:

```
$ns = @{'ns'='http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task'}
$xml = Select-Xml -Xml $xmldoc -XPath "//ns:Task/ns:Triggers/ns:TimeTrigger/ns:StartBoundary" -Namespace $ns
$xml.Node.Value = $newvalue
```

But how to acquire path if all I have is the node name?  Is there a method to do this, or do I have to iterate through all the elements until I find a node name match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the only information provided is the tag name, you can use XPath `descendant-or-self` axis (`//`) and `name()` -or `local-name()`- to match the target elements anywhere in the XML document :

```
$xmlInfo = Select-Xml -Xml $xmldoc -XPath "//*[name()='StartBoundary']"
```

Comment: So I don't need the full path.  I guess that string is not so difficult to compose after all.  I found this introduction helpful: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-xpath-to-locate-information-in-xml-documents/  full XPath specification here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be  working...

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$xmldoc =  New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmldoc.Load($xmlfile)
# user selects node, provides $newvalue
[System.Xml.XmlNode]$xmlnode = $xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName($node)[0].ChildNodes[0]
$xmlnode.InnerText = $newvalue
$xmldoc.Save($xmlfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your XPath to:

```
$node = 'StartBoundary'
$xmlInfo = Select-Xml -Xml $xmldoc -XPath "//ns:$node" -Namespace $ns
$xmlInfo.Node.Value = $newvalue
```

Comment: This is what I was experimenting with.  I haven't tested it but I think it should work.  The problem is composing the string for `-Xpath` ... which is why I'm looking for a solution that does not require the path or a method that provides it.

Comment: So yeah, there is no real difference between `"//ns:$node"` and `"//*[name()='StartBoundary']"` other than the latter does not require a namespace.  Also, the post above actual does `compose` the xpath.  Put what element name you want in `$node` and the XPath expression will find it.  As opposed to hard-coding in `'StartBoundary'`.